# Cannot find the kernel-headers although installed

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, fedora

I have written a test module for linux kernel. This module needs headers `<linux/config.h>` and `<asm/system.h>`. When I issued `make`, it gave me error
`fatal error: linux/config.h: No such file or directory`
and in the same way if I comment `config.h` header then it says `asm/system.h: No such file or directory`. I tried searching for the problem and came across solution that these headers belong ti `kernel-headers` package. I installed this package (although it was already installed on my system). But then to it cannot find these two headers. I found solution of soft-linking `autoconf.h` from `/usr/src/` path, but unfortunately I could not find any headers folder installed on this path. Can anyone tell me where is the problem with my code? I am using F20 operating system and kernel version is 3.12.9-301.fc20.x86_64.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that your Makefile don't know where to search for kernel headers. Can you try with this Makefile : just type `make` and it should build using kernel-headers of your current running kernel.

```
# Run this Makefile as follows:
# (MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
#

KDIR= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build

obj-m := test.o

all:
$(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules

install:
$(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules_install
depmod -a

clean:
rm -f *~
$(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) clean
```

Comment: still the problem persist. linux/config.h is not found.

Answer (score 1):

> The file include/linux/config.h has been removed from 2.6.19 kernel.
>   So remember this if you build your favorite module against the new
>   2.6.19 kernel and you get an error similar to this:

```
fatal error: linux/config.h: No such file or directory
 #include <linux/config.h>
```

src:

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-kernel-70/removal-of-include-linux-config-h-file-in-2-6-19-kernel-506363/

Answer (score 0):

You may try just touching the linux/config.h file and try make.